# xskak displaying board after a certain move

Tags: xskak

Using the following code, I have 2 questions:
1- Is it possible to insert the repeated \xskakloop code in the preamble instead of repeating it after each game?

2- Is it possible to start displaying the board, starting from example 2, after a certain move (for example from move 4) instead of move 1?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xskak, chessboard}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\makeatletter
\providecommand\xskak@beforecomment{}
\makeatother

\newcommand\getmovestyle[1]{
\ifthenelse
  {\equal{#1}{N}}
  {\def\mymovestyle{[clockwise=false,style=knight]curvemove}}
  {\ifthenelse
    {\equal{#1}{}}
    {\def\mymovestyle{curvemove}}
    {\def\mymovestyle{straightmove}}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}

Ruy Lopez Opening\\

\newchessgame
\chessboard[tinyboard]{}

Example1 \\

\hidemoves{
1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. d4 Nf6 4. dxe5 Nxe4 5. g3 f6 
}% do not leave an empty line before this closing }
\xskakloop{%
\getmovestyle{\xskakget{piecechar}}%
\chessboard[tinyboard,
 pgfstyle=\mymovestyle, color=blue!50,
  markmoves=\xskakget{move}, pgfshortenend=0.3em, arrow=to,  markstyle=\dots\, markfield=\xskakget{movefrom},
  emphfields=\xskakget{moveto}, setfen=\xskakget{nextfen}]\\
  \xskakget{opennr}
  \xskakget{lan}
  \xskakget{nag}
  \par
  }%

\clearpage

\newchessgame
\chessboard[tinyboard]{}

Example2 \\

\hidemoves{
1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. d4 Nf6 4. dxe5 Nxe5 5. b4 a5
}% do not leave an empty line before this closing }
\xskakloop{%
\getmovestyle{\xskakget{piecechar}}%
\chessboard[tinyboard,
 pgfstyle=\mymovestyle, color=blue!50,
  markmoves=\xskakget{move}, pgfshortenend=0.3em, arrow=to,  markstyle=\dots\, markfield=\xskakget{movefrom},
  emphfields=\xskakget{moveto}, setfen=\xskakget{nextfen}]\\
  \xskakget{opennr}
  \xskakget{lan}
  \xskakget{nag}
  \par
  }%

\clearpage

\newchessgame
\chessboard[tinyboard]{}

Example3 \\

\hidemoves{
1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. d4 Nf6 4. d5 Na5 5. b4 Nc4
}% do not leave an empty line before this closing }
\xskakloop{%
\getmovestyle{\xskakget{piecechar}}%
\chessboard[tinyboard,
 pgfstyle=\mymovestyle, color=blue!50,
  markmoves=\xskakget{move}, pgfshortenend=0.3em, arrow=to,  markstyle=\dots\, markfield=\xskakget{movefrom},
  emphfields=\xskakget{moveto}, setfen=\xskakget{nextfen}]\\
  \xskakget{opennr}
  \xskakget{lan}
  \xskakget{nag}
  \par
  }%

\clearpage

\newchessgame
\chessboard[tinyboard]{}

Example4 \\

\hidemoves{
1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. d4 Nf6 4. d5 Na5 5. c3 Nxd5
}% do not leave an empty line before this closing }
\xskakloop{%
\getmovestyle{\xskakget{piecechar}}%
\chessboard[tinyboard,
 pgfstyle=\mymovestyle, color=blue!50,
  markmoves=\xskakget{move}, pgfshortenend=0.3em, arrow=to,  markstyle=\dots\, markfield=\xskakget{movefrom},
  emphfields=\xskakget{moveto}, setfen=\xskakget{nextfen}]\\
  \xskakget{opennr}
  \xskakget{lan}
  \xskakget{nag}
  \par
  }%
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always write your own commands if you see that you are repeating things. And yes `\xskakloop` has an optional argument where you can set the initmove and the stopmove (and the step length). See the documentation on page 35.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{xskak, chessboard}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\makeatletter
\providecommand\xskak@beforecomment{}
\makeatother

\newcommand\getmovestyle[1]{
\ifthenelse
  {\equal{#1}{N}}
  {\def\mymovestyle{[clockwise=false,style=knight]curvemove}}
  {\ifthenelse
    {\equal{#1}{}}
    {\def\mymovestyle{curvemove}}
    {\def\mymovestyle{straightmove}}}}

\newcommand\mychessloop[1][]{%
 \xskakloop[#1]{%
\getmovestyle{\xskakget{piecechar}}%
\chessboard[tinyboard,
 pgfstyle=\mymovestyle, color=blue!50,
  markmoves=\xskakget{move}, pgfshortenend=0.3em, arrow=to,  markstyle=\dots\, markfield=\xskakget{movefrom},
  emphfields=\xskakget{moveto}, setfen=\xskakget{nextfen}]\\
  \xskakget{opennr}
  \xskakget{lan}
  \xskakget{nag}
  \par
  }}%

\begin{document}

\centering


Example1 
\newchessgame

\hidemoves{
1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. d4 Nf6 4. dxe5 Nxe4 5. g3 f6
}% do not leave an empty line before this closing }
\mychessloop

\clearpage

Example2 
\newchessgame

\hidemoves{
1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. d4 Nf6 4. dxe5 Nxe5 5. b4 a5
}% do not leave an empty line before this closing }
\mychessloop[initmoveid=3w]

\end{document}
```